# HTML Table and divs with flexbox in <td> and <th> unexpected behavior

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

**Goal:** I have tried using the HTML table to create a table that has a scrollable tbody and a fixed first column. Each cell in a given col should have the same width, and the height of any row should be just enough to fit the content, which is what HTML table does.

**What I have tried:** Finding this particularly difficult to implement, I have instead tried to implement a HTML table with a sticky header and first col, as mentioned here.https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa?editors=1100
However, I am noticing that HTML table is giving me problems. I have placed divs that use flexbox to align flex-items within it into td, and the table spacing is no longer working as designed.

I have read that this is due to the fact that HTML table should not have divs with complex styling inside the td and th.

**Question:** Is it possible for HTML Table to handle divs with flexbox alignment and still render as expected?

**Future thoughts:** I am considering building a table using CSS Grid, as I heard that is more flexible when it comes to the items it can hold.

Comment: Isn't that expected from a row already? Rows *do fit* (adapt) as the cell content  increases.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks. I have updated my question for more clarity.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<table>
   <colgroup>
      <col width="50%">
      <col width="50%">
   </colgroup>

   <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>3476896</td>
      <td>My first HTML</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use the colgroup tag and put the col tags in there with specific properties for each column. I put the width property there.